# Count how many times a field attribute appears in a column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, count

I'm trying to count how many times a value appears in a column on my table using Lambda or Linq.

Here's my Table properties

```
public class Vote
{
    [Key]
    public int VoteId { get; set; }

    public int CandidateId { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int ParticipantId { get; set; }
    public DateTime datecreated { get; set; }
}
```

So in my controller I'm doing this

```
public ActionResult Index(int? CategoryId, string Id)
{
    List<VoteCan> agc = new List<VoteCan>();
    if(CategoryId.HasValue)
    {
        var allcategory = db.Votes.ToList().FindAll(x => (x.CategoryId == CategoryId.Value) && (x.Id == Id)).ToList();
        //I want to count how many Candidates are in the Votes table using the candidateId
    }

    return View();
}
```

For example I want to have something like this

```
CandidateNo      Count
21358              3
21878              4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group by `CategoryId`. Use [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501(v=vs.100).aspx):-

```
List<VoteCan> results = db.Votes.GroupBy(x => x.CandidateId)
                      .Select(x => new VoteCan
                                  {
                                      CandidateNo = x.Key,
                                      Count = x.Count()
                                  }).ToList();
```

Assuming `VoteCan` class has `CandidateNo` & `Count` properties.